# why does ipcs command shows many undetached shared memory with key 0x0000000?

Tags: linux, shared-memory, ipcs

I discover many undetached shared memory with key 0x0000000 with `ipcs` like these:

```
0x00000000 585728074  nobody     777        48         0                       
0x00000000 585760843  nobody     777        48         0                       
0x00000000 586711116  nobody     777        48         0                       
0x00000000 586743885  nobody     777        48         0                       
0x00000000 587104334  nobody     777        48         0                       
0x00000000 587137103  nobody     777        48         0                       
0x00000000 587694160  nobody     777        48         0                       
0x00000000 587726929  nobody     777        48         0                       
0x00000000 588087378  nobody     777        48         0                       
0x00000000 588120147  nobody     777        48         0                       
0x00000000 588480596  nobody     777        48         0                       
0x00000000 588513365  nobody     777        48         0                       
0x00000000 588742742  nobody     777        48         0                       
0x00000000 588775511  nobody     777        48         0                       
0x00000000 588939352  nobody     777        48         0                       
0x00000000 588972121  nobody     777        48         0                       
0x00000000 589135962  nobody     777        48         0                       
0x00000000 589168731  nobody     777        48         0                       
0x00000000 589791324  nobody     777        48         0                       
0x00000000 589824093  nobody     777        48         0                       
0x00000000 589987934  nobody     777        48         0
```

It is quite strange because the value of `nattach` parameters are all 0, which means no process is attaching to them and they should be deleted in this case.

What am I missing? I don't know which process causes this. Is there any way to find out?

Comment: Have you created the shared memory segments and not deleted them?

Comment: @saai63. Suppose we don't delete the shms we have created, then it should only have shms corresponding to those keys. Why with `0x00000000` key?

Comment: @atuly: They were probably created with key as IPC_PRIVATE and hence the keys are 0x00000000